# Is "sparkling" a synonym for "carbonated" when it comes to drinks?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives, synonyms

I wonder whether "sparkling" can function as a synonym for "carbonated" or "soda" when it comes to fizzy drinks. Is there any difference or can they be used interchangably?

Comment: By [_soda_](http://popvssoda.com/), do you mean the clear variety of fizzy drink, or _all_ carbonated beverages regardless of coloration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

Two of the [best-selling brands of bottled water in the UK](https://www.statista.com/statistics/308644/leading-brands-of-bottled-mineral-water-in-the-uk/) are *Highland Spring* and *Buxton Spring*. Two of the [best-selling brands in the US](https://www.statista.com/statistics/188312/top-bottled-still-water-brands-in-the-united-states/) are *Aquafina* and *Dasani*. As the composite illustration below shows, all of these currently describe the carbonated version of their product in these countries as **‘sparkling’**.

[image: Sparkling mineral waters]

Like it or not, if that’s what it says on the bottle it is being *used* as a synonym, at least in relation to water.

(From my observation, those people who drink sweetened carbonated drinks usual refer to them by their brand name.)

*Disclaimer*

I have no connection with any of these products, nor do I endorse them in any way. Where I live the water that comes out of the tap (faucet) is just as good as the ‘still’ product, and far cheaper.

Comment: "*if that’s what it says on the bottle it must function as a synonym*" I am not aware of any such rule.

Comment: @michael.hor257k — I'm not sure what your point is. Perhaps I could have phrased it differently. This is English Language and Usage. I was demonstrating that contemporary usage to describe what the OP referred to as carbonated etc. was indeed "sparkling". Of course that does not mean that they are a linguistic synonym, but the OP is asking about usage.

Comment: I guess my point is that *sparkling* suggests **natural** effervescence - and that manufacturers subverting the term to make their products more appealing does not constitute an authority on usage. On the contrary: the fact that they feel the need to do so supports my assertion.

Comment: @michael.hor257k — I'm obviously too subtle for you. When I wrote "like it or not" I was tempted to follow it with "(and I don't)", but I know from experience that subjective asides like that would attract accusations of arrogance, having pretentions and being opinionated. However I don't actually accept your point about natural effervescence (must admit I've never encountered it — have you?) being "sparkling". I'd apply sparkling to diamonds, stars, fire crackers, even eyes (Gilbert and Sullivan), but you really need a camera crew to make fizz sparkle.

Comment: You are obviously too [something] for me, but I prefer to stay on the point.

Answer (score 2):

Sparkling is more trendy and used primarily in restaurants. Example: a waiter would not ask you if you prefer "regular or carbonated water." Carbonated you will find in the ingredients section of a drink that is fizzy. So, to appear savvy in a restaurant, whether posh or not, ask for 'Sparkling' whatever.

Comment: Please provide some sort of evidence in support of your assertion so that people can judge whether it is correct or not. This could be through an internet or ngram search for "sparkling water" or "still or sparkling?" and the like and should include a national context. You would find it useful to complete the guided tour (your lack of badge indicates you have not) and read what constitutes a good answer.

Comment: The way one *speaks* of these things in a restaurant is not likely to appear commonly in Google's corpus (until we start digitising and automatically subtitling all the background noise surrounding Google users in restaurants) :o). FWIW, here in the UK at least, I'd second their assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. The online Oxford Dictionary gives one definition of [**sparkling**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sparkling) as:

> **2** (of a drink) effervescent; fizzy.
>
> effervescent, fizzy, **carbonated**, aerated, gassy, bubbly, bubbling,
>   fizzing, foaming, frothy

Comment: There was once a long discussion about this in chat, where it seemed this was regional to the UK and largely unknown in the USA.

Comment: @Spagirl - I wouldn't say it's unknown in the US.  Not super common, but "sparkling water" is quite familiar, and "sparkling wine" is certainly heard.

Comment: Well, *sparkling wine* contains carbon dioxide as a result of natural fermentation, while *carbonated* suggests an artificial process.

Comment: @michael.hor257k that's true of the good stuff, but it's not universal. And other drinks can also be made fizzy naturally or by pumping in CO2, for example ginger beer.

Comment: @HotLicks In the chat it seemed folk would barely accept the UK usage as valid even when provided with pictorial evidence! But I was merely reporting as anecdote to raise the possibility and awareness that it may not be universally instantly understood.

Comment: @ChrisH I didn't say it was universal. I am saying there are nuances, so the two are not exactly synonyms (that's what the question here is about, isn't it?).

Comment: Link to the source of your quotation please. That way we can judge its authority and nationality.

Comment: @David -- There **is** a link.

Comment: @HotLicks — so there is. I didn't notice it. It would be better if it were more obviously related to the quotation and the source were quoted in the answer. Perhaps I'll edit it.

Comment: Please read [how to reference material written by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). You **must** give a full, reproducible citation that can be clearly read in plaintext (hypertext links alone don't count as they don't survive plaintext reproduction), and the bulk of your answer should consist primarily of your own words, **not** someone else's copypasta.

Comment: Put not your faith in dictionaries. As a scientist I know that carbonated means it has carbon dioxide in it, whereas aerated means it has air (with 5% carbon dioxide) in it. As for those being synonymous with frothy... Very frothy!

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about sparkling wine, then no, sparkling and carbonated are NOT synonymous. I don't think that's what you were talking about, but in case you're interested... Because sparkling wine is not carbonated (well, not most- there is a very cheap version of sparkling wine made with carbonation). Tank Method is the name for the sparkling wine making process. Unlike the 'Traditional Fermentation', whereby the second fermentation happens in bottle. Tank Method takes place in a large closed pressure tank, whereas carbonation is the process of adding a solution of carbon dioxide gas.